# How to manipulate elements in a file in Unix Shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I have a UNIX Shell script question. The following line of code:

sed '15s/.*/1/' file1 > file2

goes down file1 until the 15th element (i.e., row), changes it, and writes the modified file into file2.  The file looks like this (“Vertical”):

```
HEADER 1
RECORD: COL1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
1
1
0
1
0
0
```

Now, what if the content of the file is “horizontal”, like this:

```
HEADER 1
RECORD:COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5
1,0,4,0,3
```

How would I modify the above code to change, say, the last element (i.e., change the ‘3’ to ‘0’)?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use awk, which is very good at manipulating fields in a record.

In this case, you'll need to declare that the field separator is a comma, the output field separator is also a comma. I'm going to assume you want to change a particular record number (i.e. line/row number)

```
awk '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","}
    NR == 3 {$NF = 0}
    {print}
' <<END
HEADER 1
RECORD:COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5
1,0,4,0,
END
```

Lots more info on the [awk tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info).